# how to print the button only one time in a map function still be able to access the iteration value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, material-ui

I am using formik in material-ui for a form. I have created a map function for printing text fields. Now, I just want to display the Submit button only one time and I achieved that also by targeting index. But the thing is, when I am trying to access the iterative item, I am able to access only the last Item

My Code :

```
{["Name", "E-Mail", "Phone"].map(
            (item, index, arrLength) => {
              let tempItem = tempItem.toLowerCase().replace("-", "");
              return (
                <Fragment key={index}>
                  <Grid item>
                    <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      id={tempItem}
                      name={tempItem}
                      label={item}
                      onChange={formik.handleChange}
                      error={
                        formik.touched.tempItem
                          ? formik.touched.tempItem&&
                            Boolean(formik.errors.tempItem)
                          : null
                      }
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  {arrLength.length - 1 === index && (
                    <Grid item>
                       <Button
                        disabled={formik.errors.tempItem ? true : false}
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        type="submit"
                      >
                        Submit /* when I am trying to access the item and tempItem only the last of 
                        array is being accessible. As I am using formik to show errors, when I am
                        clicking the submit button it should check error in all other fields, and if
                        no errors then only the button should display, but in this case, the button
                        checks only the last field(phone) and if its valid, submit button is showing
                        even though the other fields are invalid */
                      </Button>
                    </Grid>
                  )}
                </Fragment>
```

Comment: Dude, you don't have to map into the entire form, just map TextField.

Comment: No, if i map only the text field, all the text fields will display in one grid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it Out,

```
<Button
 color="primary"
 variant="contained"
 type="submit"
 disabled={Object.values(formik.errors).every((x) => x == "") ? false : true}>
    
  Submit
 
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to map into the entire form, just map `TextField` like this:

```
 return (
    <Fragment>
      {["Name", "E-Mail", "Phone"].map((item,index) => {
        let tempItem = tempItem.toLowerCase().replace("-", "");
        return (
        <Grid item key={index}>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            id={tempItem}
            name={tempItem}
            label={item}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            error={
              formik.touched.tempItem
                ? formik.touched.tempItem && Boolean(formik.errors.tempItem)
                : null
            }
          />
        </Grid>
      )})}
      <Grid item>
        <Button
          disabled={formik.errors ? true : false}
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          type="submit"
        >
          Submit /* when I am trying to access the item and tempItem only the
          last of array is being accessible. As I am using formik to show
          errors, when I am clicking the submit button it should check error in
          all other fields, and if no errors then only the button should
          display, but in this case, the button checks only the last
          field(phone) and if its valid, submit button is showing even though
          the other fields are invalid */
        </Button>
      </Grid>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: When I am following this, formik is always disabling the button, as formik.errors always exist at least as an empty object . Thats why i did  <Button
                        disabled={formik.errors.tempItem ? true : false}
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        type="submit"
                      >
                        Submit 
                      </Button> which will concentrate on each items inside the formik.errors object